# brew - How list/identify packages that depend on unsupported macOS

Tags: homebrew

brew doctor reports: `Error: unknown or unsupported macOS version :mountain_lion`

This is a problem having nothing to do with my current version of the macOS I'm using (Catalina), but rather because I have packages that seem to only work/depend on the older macOS version.

How might I identify the packages that are triggering this error?  Over the years, I have accumulated 314 packages installed using brew!

Thank you to anyone with some advice.

- E

Comment: Maybe try `brew doctor --verbose`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... but it did not work. - E

Comment: What’s the output of `cd  $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps ; grep -r ':mountain_lion'`? Do you have matching files outside of `homebrew/homebrew-core`?

Comment: @bfontaine Thank you for your suggestion.  The command returned an empty result from the `/Library/Taps` directory.  This does not mean your suggestion might not be the way to go.  Just prior to seeing your suggestion, I deleted the list of packages that brew had "removed".  The way I said it does not make sense, but that is what is confusing: brew said it removed applications such as `mongodb`, but seems to rely on the user to delete them outright.  The end result => no more mountain lion error.  Based on the output of what you provided, I'm going to close this issue.

Comment: @bfontaine If you put your suggestion as a response, I will mark it as an answer. For completeness, while not the answer to the question, my deleting the files associated with what brew reported as being removed, got rid of the offending error.  If you might, it may be useful to include that as a "PS" in the answer.  - E

Comment: @Edmund'sEcho can’t you answer your own question? That’d be easier :)

Comment: @bfontaine Yes.  I just did not want you to loose any credit... I'm not sure how the point system works so I did not want to inadvertently "take" what was yours.

Comment: @Edmund'sEcho No worries, I have enough points already :)